# How to edit the content of the old app in developer console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I am having an android app already published in Google play store , now I want to **update** its description and screenshot only.

Can I update it and save it as draft ***before publishing*** it in the play store (like **iTunesConnect** for apple).

When I edit its content its showing like this,

[image]

If I click this **Submit** button will it save as a draft or directly published in the play store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it will update your app in play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I click this Submit button will it save as a draft or directly published in the play store.

It will directly published in the play store. After your app was published to the Play Store, you can't save as draft.